# Save a new dataframe for every iteration of for loop based on Age Column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I need to save each iteration results as a new list or Dataframe. As of Now I m only able to print the last iteration of the loop.I need each iteration or array saved in Dataframe.

```
    for unique_age in sorted(Data.Age.unique()):
        df_result = Data.query(F"Age == {unique_age}")
        df_result['Percentile']=df_result.Total_Revenue.rank(pct=True)*100
     data_list.append(df_result)
    df_result
```

[Data:][1]
[Expected output:][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gshKe.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9zpU.png

Comment: I think this line `data_list.append(df_result)` is outside of the loop in your code, move it inside the loop and your list will have a dataframe for each iteration

Comment: tried as u suggested still its the same output not as required...

Comment: Your expected output looks like you just want to sort the Age column? @ShikhaRai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are adding each dataframes into a list as each element. It is a good approach, but the dataframes will not be named. So, instead use the dictionary and keep names as keys, and dataframes as values.

```
data_list = {}  
for unique_age in sorted(Data.Age.unique()):
    df_result = Data.query(F"Age == {unique_age}")
    df_result['Percentile']=df_result.Total_Revenue.rank(pct=True)*100
    name = "age"+str(unique_age)
    data_list[name] = df_result
```

Afterwards you can call by their names such as `data_list["age10"]` or something like that, instead of calling them by indexes `data_list[1]`.

Or if you are feeling spicy, may be this is something you would be interested in. This creates new variables (here dataframes) in each loops

```
for unique_age in sorted(Data.Age.unique()):
    df_result = Data.query(F"Age == {unique_age}")
    df_result['Percentile']=df_result.Total_Revenue.rank(pct=True)*100
    exec('df_{}age = df_result'.format(unique_age))
```